# Is there any reason why this wouldn't be creating text here?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
UNEXPOSED = '~'
POKEMON = "☺"
FLAG = "♥"
EXPOSED = "0"
possible_adjacent_amount = ["0", "1", "2" "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]

def draw_board(self, board):

        self.delete()
        index = 0
        print(board)
        for row in range(self._grid_size):
            for column in range(self._grid_size):

                x1 = column*self._cell_size
                y1 = row * self._cell_size
                x2 = x1 + self._cell_size
                y2 = y1 + self._cell_size

                self.x1 = x1
                self.y1 = y1
                self.x2 = x2
                self.y2 = y2
                #bounding_box = ((int (x1), int (y1)), (int (x2), int (y2)))

                centre_pixel = (x1 + (x2 - x1) // 2, y1 + (y2 - y1) // 2)
                self.pos_to_pixel[(row, column)] = centre_pixel

                #tp = self.create_text((100, 100), text='1')
                print(board[index])
                if board[index] ==UNEXPOSED:
                    self.create_rectangle (x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="dark green", tags="rect")
                if board[index] in possible_adjacent_amount :
                    # TODO why doesn't this work...?
                    self.create_text(self.position_to_pixel ((row, column)), text = board[index])
                    self.create_rectangle (x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="light green", tags="rect")
                if board[index] == FLAG:
                    self.create_rectangle (x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="red", tags="rect")
                if board[index] == POKEMON:
                    self.create_text ((centre_pixel), text=board[index])
                    self.create_rectangle (x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="yellow", tags="rect")

                index += 1
```

The board input will be something like `0~~~1~~12~~3`

The idea is that it will take the board index and then create text at the center pixel of the board index that will be the numbers which in this case would be 0, 1, 1, 2, 3

Comment: this piece of code has many undefined variables. i.e. `UNEXPOSED`, `POKEMON`, `possible_adjacent_amount`, `FLAG `and `POKEMON`. What do they do?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that it is just things that are going to be in the game string... Position to pixel just takes those row, col co ordinates and returns the center pixel given those row, col co-ordinates.

Comment: tell a example of board argument in function definition?

Comment: The board input will be something like 0~~~1~~12~~3, I fixed it... The issue was I was drawing the rectangles on top of the numbers because I was trying to create the text first...

Answer (score 0):

You if you want the numbers to be drawn on the rectangles you need to create the text after you create the rectangles otherwise you will create text behind the rectangles.